# AutoFac Singleton Instances

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

Is there any issue with declaring the singleton in terms of thread safety as follows :-
builder.Register(c => new Wrapper()).As().SingleInstance();

Also whats the lifetime of the instance variables inside a singleton class
For ex :-

```
Class Wrapper 
{

public CosmosDbCollection graphCollection {get; private set}

 public DbManager DocDBManager { get; private set; }

public Wrapper()
{
 initialize();
}

private initialize()
{
  // get cosmos collection and store it in the graph collection object
}
}
```

Further docdbmanager will be used by every request to query cosmos db for particular documents.
Is marking Wrapper singleton a good idea?

Also I have another wrapper class which has initialize as public method and being called in the following manner :-

```
IWrapper2 wrapper2 = AppContainer.Container.Resolve<IWrapper2>();
wrapper2.initialize();
```

This initialize will initialize some of the member variables of the singleton class. Is it ok to do this?

Comment: `Also whats the lifetime of the instance variables inside a singleton class` Generally speaking, the same as the class that contains it (i.e. the lifetime of the app).

Comment: `Is there any issue with declaring the singleton in terms of thread safety as follows` Is the class, and all of its state (e.g. `graphCollection`), thread-safe?

Comment: There is no issue declaring singletons like that. Testing resolving it with multiple threads, you'll find that `Wrapper`'s constructor is called a single time.

Comment: thank you! I think i could have checked this thing by putting debug point where i am registering all these dependencies...

Comment: @mjwills also in another class which is registered as singleton i am calling initialize method later to set the instances in the class...IMonitoringWrapper wrapper = AppContainer.Container.Resolve<IWrapper>(); wrapper.initialize(); its being called at the startup..is it ok?

Comment: `initialize` is `private` so I am not sure how you are achieving that.

Comment: @mjwills this is different class which has initialize as public method

Comment: @mjwills i edited the same question with the details

Comment: @mjwills do you still need a separate question?